# DateTime.Parse Issue Australian TimeZone

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datetime

I am working with Australian timezone.When i trying with Parse Exact,it always throwing exception.How can i solve this issue.Please note i need a solution which is working in Australian timezone.

```
    DateTime fdt = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null)
```

Comment: Australia typically uses "dd/MM/yyyy" format. What does your `FromDate` text look like?

Comment: What exception is being thrown, and what's the value you're trying to parse? Note that `DateTime.ParseExact` won't use a time zone at all unless you specify a format which uses one, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What exception? And why is the Culture `null` ?

Comment: FromDate is consisting of format 'mm/dd/yy"(eg:10/30/11).i want to convert to a datetime which is also having mm/dd/yyyy format.Exception that thrown is {"The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."}

Comment: Have you tried 10/30/2011? or failing that 30/10/2011

Comment: in question you are use 'MM/dd/yyyy' (month/day/year) format. But in comment above you mention that you use 'mm/dd/yyyy' (minutes/day/year) . Which one you are really use?

Comment: i put like this DateTime fdt = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null)

Comment: System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        String format = "M/d/yy";fdt = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, format, provider);at that time also i getting this exception The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

Comment: converted date should be of format MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Please use the _edit_ link under the question. Add the exception details and properly format them.

Comment: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

Answer (score 0):

If you use a formatter like "MM/dd/yyyy", the parsing has nothing to do with the time zone your in. It will just use the format from the formatter to parse the date. In this case Month/days/year

Comment: When you do not use a formatting string, it will take the culture setting from the current thread. But I think you are looking for the format string like "dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: i also tried System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        String format = "M/dd/yy";
fdt = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "MM/dd/yy", null);
At that time aslo i getting a n enception 
{"The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."}

Comment: Your format string overrides all formatting, use something like: "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: fdt = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, format, provider);it is throwing earlier excption

Answer (score 0):

As far as you pass to ParseExact method null IFormatProvider parameter value, system try to use your  DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo value for parsing date string. If your machine culture has DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator different from '/' (i.e. dot character) the date string that use slash as date separator cannot be parsed.

Try to use this: `DateTime.ParseExact("10/30/11", "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` or in case you are definitely know that this string in an Australian format you may use this: `DateTime.ParseExact("10/30/11", "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"))`